# How to escape and unescape strings with jQuery and mySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, textarea

I have a field in my database that has a freetext area, and uses quotes for many things. On my website, that field is shown in a textarea, but I can't simply put the value between the textarea tags. I need to be able to set it with javascript. I use jQuery to do this, via:

```
jQuery('#notes').val('{NOTES}');
```

Since the text can have single or double quotes, I'm unsure how to pass this from mySQL, to PHP, to jQuery so I can put it in my textarea. Has anyone done this before?

Problem solved using:

```
jQuery('#notes').val(jQuery('#your-hidden-div-id').html());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [addslashes()](http://php.net/addslashes) from PHP to escape quotes so they can be used inside JavaScript strings:

```
jQuery('#notes').val('<?php echo addslashes($your_string); ?>');
```

From your code I assume you may use some sort of template engine so you should add `addslashes` where you assign {NOTES}.

If you have newlines inside your data you may need to remove them too as this will break JS string (remove with a PCRE regular expression for example). Another way would be to load your data inside a hidden <div> and then:

```
jQuery('#notes').val(jQuery('#your-hidden-div-id').html());
```

Comment: a serverside language nested inside a client side language? That's awfull in my opinion.

Comment: Yes, that's why I have suggested to addslashes() where he is assigning {NOTES}

Comment: Using the hidden DIV worked perfectly.  Thanks a lot for that suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Are you worried about double-escaping?  Simply pulling it out of the database won't change any of the characters.  How do you pass it from PHP to Javascript?  An AJAX request?  If you receive the data as text, there shouldn't be any escaping either.

Where you need to be careful is sending it from jQuery back to MySQL via PHP.

Comment: so if he puts this string `'some data` where {NOTES} is in that javascript line, what happens?

Comment: If I pass a string with mixed quotes into val(''); it'll break because of the quotes.  I need a way to escape them so that they quotes remain, and then unescape them without messing up the function call.

Comment: @Atrox yes, I was trying to get @Pickle to see it :)

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery('#notes').text('{NODES}')`

should escape your string. Im not sure if it works on textearea's but i think so.

You can also try to use the following jQuery plugin:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/escape

Some code like this should work than:

`jQuery('#notes').val($.escape('{NODES}'))`

**UPDATE**

This should work aswell

```
{NODES}.replace('\'','\\\'');
{NODES}.replace('\"','\\\"');
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried that as well, but I don't want escaped text in the textarea.